# Alert selected text from tinyMCE not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

I want to alert the selected text from tinyMCE editor in Moodle. This is working fine in google chrome but not working in IE.

**alert selected text:**

```
alert(tinyMCEPopup.editor.selection.getContent()); // working in chrome not working in IE
```

**alert entire text in editor**

```
alert(tinyMCEPopup.editor.getContent());  //working in both chrome and IE
```

How can I alert the selected text in IE browser??

I am using **IE version 11** , **tinyMCE 3.5** and **Moodle 2.7**

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is updating your TinyMCE to a latest version if possible.

This link says they just added compatibility for IE 11 in TinyMCE 3.5.9 release

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32792

But, for IE everything is on luck ;-)

Comment: I am using 3.5.10, which is latest version.

Comment: TinyMCE 4.1.7 is latest, so you may migrate to it if it's possible.

Comment: Visit the home page

[link](http://www.tinymce.com/index.php)

and try this command after selecting any text

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent()`